# Is it possible to use Selenium in the Net 5 dot net/runtime MS base image

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a basic web page scraper written in Net 5 which current uses Selenium. I’d like to run this in a container so have looked at using the MS official dotnet/runtime base image but hit errors when trying to start the WebDriver so assume it’s because chrome and Selenium isn’t installed.

I’ve found various solutions online which involve running selenium grid in its own container using their own official selenium instances, but nothing that I can find runs it in the same container. I don’t need to scale instances so grid seems a bit overkill for my requirements (a single headless chrome instance).

Can anyone point me in the right direction if this is possible?

Rich

Comment: Have you tried installing chrome and webdriver inside the container?

Comment: No, was looking for any guides on how I can do that.

Comment: there are some manuals in [goolge](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk02FBoWrty2TnMHFrxRXFoGVZZR4ug%3A1613947682192&ei=IuMyYMuVC-CTwPAP96-XqAY&q=install+selenium+chromedriver+debian) , for example [this one](https://gist.github.com/ziadoz/3e8ab7e944d02fe872c3454d17af31a5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have the docker app running
2. Create a folder somewhere
3. Create a file without an extension called dockerfile inside that folder => create a txt file and remove the .txt
4. Inside that file paste the following

```html
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

# Install Chrome
 RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 apt-transport-https \
 ca-certificates \
 curl \
 gnupg \
 hicolor-icon-theme \
 libcanberra-gtk* \
 libgl1-mesa-dri \
 libgl1-mesa-glx \
 libpango1.0-0 \
 libpulse0 \
 libv4l-0 \
 fonts-symbola \
 --no-install-recommends \
 && curl -sSL https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
 && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list \
 && apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
 google-chrome-stable \
 --no-install-recommends \
 && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

5. Open a cmd and navigate inside that folder and type: docker build -t dotnet_selenium . && docker run -it dotnet_selenium . Where dotnet_selenium is the name of the image
6. To verify that the chrome has been installed type in the bash: google-chrome --version it should return
   Google Chrome 88.0.4324.182

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, works perfectly, thanks!